# How to get a text ("N/A") for my pivoted data where values do not exist against pivoted column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please find sample input tables named as Table1 and Table2.

Table1 :

| id | Dates | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 Sept'23 | 445.23 |
| 1 | 20 Sept'23 | 470.33 |
| 1 | 22 Sept'23 | 500.33 |

Table2 :

| id | Dates |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 Sept'23 |
| 1 | 19 Sept'23 |
| 1 | 20 Sept'23 |
| 1 | 21 Sept'23 |
| 1 | 22 Sept'23 |
| 1 | 23 Sept'23 |
| 1 | 24 Sept'23 |

Desired output :

| id | 18 Sept'23 | 19 Sept'23 | 20 Sept'23 | 21 Sept'23 | 22 Sept'23 | 23 Sept'23 | 24 Sept'23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 445.23 | N/A | 470.33 | N/A | 500.33 | N/A | N/A |

```
Declare @PvtQry nvarchar(max)
Declare @Qry nvarchar(max)

SELECT @PvtQry = COALESCE(@PvtQry+',','') + QUOTENAME([Dates]) FROM Table2 WHERE id = 1 Order by Dates Desc

Set @Qry = 'Select id,'+@PvtQry+' INTO ##Tbl_Temp
        FROM (Select id,Dates,Sales as SalesValue FROM Table1) AS Source
        PIVOT (Max (isnull(Cast(SalesValue as nvarchar(100)),''N/A'') FOR [Dates] IN ('+@PvtQry+') AS Pvt'
EXEC sp_executesql @Qry
SELECT * FROM ##Tbl_Temp
```

> Error Message:
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: You'll might be better off with conditional aggregation to achieve this, or (and likely this is better) do the pivoting in your application layer.

Comment: I agree with Thom A, this should, if possible, be done in the presentation layer. What is the purpose of this query, is it to supply data to a report? Explain the context and you'll probably find a much easier route.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Actually the context is I have to download sales data each week using python which hits internally to this SQL query and yes this download feature is given on reports.

Answer (score 0):

The T-SQL generated in `@qry` is not valid, so I refactored it to work.

I moved the code to insert `N/A`  from the `PIVOT` to the `SELECT` clause, the following is a sample query.

```sql
WITH source AS (
    SELECT t2.id, dates = FORMAT(t2.dates, 'dd MMM yy'), t1.sales
    FROM Table2 t2
    JOIN Table1 t1
        ON t2.id = t1.id
        AND t2.dates = t1.dates
)
Select id,[24 Sep 23] = IsNull(FORMAT([24 Sep 23], '0.00'), 'N/A'),[23 Sep 23] = IsNull(FORMAT([23 Sep 23], '0.00'), 'N/A'),[22 Sep 23] = IsNull(FORMAT([22 Sep 23], '0.00'), 'N/A'),[21 Sep 23] = IsNull(FORMAT([21 Sep 23], '0.00'), 'N/A'),[20 Sep 23] = IsNull(FORMAT([20 Sep 23], '0.00'), 'N/A'),[19 Sep 23] = IsNull(FORMAT([19 Sep 23], '0.00'), 'N/A'),[18 Sep 23] = IsNull(FORMAT([18 Sep 23], '0.00'), 'N/A')
FROM source
PIVOT (
    Max(sales) 
    FOR dates
    IN ([24 Sep 23],[23 Sep 23],[22 Sep 23],[21 Sep 23],[20 Sep 23],[19 Sep 23],[18 Sep 23]) 
    ) AS Pvt
```

To generate this code dynamically you need to use an additional variable to use in the `SELECT` clause, that cast the sales value to a string and manage the null value, in the following way:

```sql
DECLARE @dateFormat NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'dd MMM yy';
DECLARE @PvtQryForSelect nvarchar(max)
SELECT @PvtQryForSelect = COALESCE(@PvtQryForSelect+',','') +
    CONCAT(QUOTENAME(FORMAT([Dates],@dateFormat)),' = IsNull(FORMAT(', QUOTENAME(FORMAT([Dates], @dateFormat)), ', ''0.00''), ''N/A'')') FROM Table2 WHERE id = 1 Order by Dates Desc;
```